# error: AJAX call within AJAX response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, post

I am working with a file to interact with an API.  First the API sends some HTML and Javascript to create a search form, then the API can process the query of that search form.

I am having some problems with my second request, which is called within the success function of the first request (this seems to be the problem!). Here's the code I'm working with.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "https://vq3rsgkd94.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/deploy",
  crossDomain: true,
  data: JSON.stringify({
    "stage": "load",
    "fields": ["first_name", "last_name", "graduation_year"]
  }),

  success: function(response) {
    response = JSON.parse(response);
    $(response.html).prependTo("#content");
    $(response.scripts).appendTo("body");
  },

  complete: function() {
    //get field inputs
    var fieldInput = {
      "first_name_query": "",
      "last_name_query": "",
      "graduation_year_query": ""
    };

    $('form').find('input[type=search]').each(function(index, value) {
      var variableName = value.name;
      var fieldId = "#" + value.name;

      $(fieldId).keyup(function() {
          variableName = $(this).val();
          fieldInput[value.name + "_query"] = variableName
          console.log(value.name + ":" + fieldInput[value.name + "_query"]);
        })
        .keyup();
    });

    $('#search_form').submit(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://vq3rsgkd94.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/deploy",
        data: JSON.stringify({
          "stage": "search",
          "fields": ["first_name", "last_name", "graduation_year"],
          "query": {
            "first_name": fieldInput["first_name_query"]
          }
        }),

        success: function(response) {
          response = JSON.parse(response);
          console.log(response);
        }
      });

    })

  }
});
```

When trying to parse the response, I get unexpected token: o.  If I run this code outside of the first ajax request like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "https://vq3rsgkd94.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/deploy",
  data: JSON.stringify({
    "stage": "search",
    "fields": ["first_name", "last_name", "graduation_year"],
    "query": {
      "first_name": "Bob"
    }
  }),


  success: function(response) {
    response = JSON.parse(response);
    console.log(response);
  }
});
```

I don't have any problem and the code executes normally.  So the problem seems to be running one Ajax call inside another's success response, but I don't know why?  I can probably do things another way instead, but wanted to see if anyone had some insight into why this doesn't work.

Comment: why not do delegated binds? - http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

Comment: jQuery will make it an object if it is JSON....

Answer (score 2):

The error you are getting suggests that you are trying to parse an object with `JSON.parse`
since

```
var x = {}
console.log(x.toString()) //> [object Object]
JSON.parse(x)
// Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
//    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
//    at <anonymous>:3:6
```

Are you sure that response is a string in the second case

Instead of explicitly converting the JSON allow jquery to parse it for you with `dataType: 'json'`

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "https://vq3rsgkd94.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/deploy",
  data: JSON.stringify({
    "stage":"search",
    "fields":["first_name","last_name","graduation_year"],
    "query":{"first_name": fieldInput["first_name_query"] }
  }),
  dataType: 'json'
)}
```

Comment: Actually when I set a breakpoint and do console.log(response), I get Object {errorMessage: "Unexpected token &", errorType: "SyntaxError", stackTrace: Array[0]}

Comment: and if I do console.log(response.toString()), I get [object Object], which explains my original error

Comment: I tried setting dataType:'json' and nothing changed.

Comment: I suggest you make a [codepen](http://codepen.io/pen/) of your html and code. It would better help folks understand your problem

Comment: I made a Codepen and the Codepen worked...  This means it something to do with the Nationbuilder site so I will have to follow up with them. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem ended up being pretty strange. I'm developing an API for Nationbuilder platform (maybe my first mistake).  For unknown reasons, Nationbuilder was appending a authenticity token to any request made, which my LAMBDA based API couldn't parse.  Just in case anyone else is in the same very tiny boat as I was, I ended up using GET requests instead of POST requests and Nationbuilder stopped appending the authenticity token.

Also, if anyone is using Lambda, I ended up switching to Digital Ocean hosted Express JS and am much happier.

Comment: I'm in the same very tiny boat as you. What a bizarre thing to do. Nationbuilder being not helpful at all.

Comment: I did! So Nationbuilder uses the liquid templating engine, there's a minified file that is included in each page. This page includes an AJAX event handler which binds to the `beforeSend` jQuery provides.

This event handler detects if the request is either a query string or an object, and will "helpfully" try and either, append or add as a property, respectively, the authenticity token to your request. However, the check is naive: when you stringify a JSON object as the body of a request, that happens _before_ the `beforeSend` event is called. As such by the time the check occurs, your (1/2)

Comment: ...body is now a string. This event handler incorrectly assumes _any_ string will be in the form of a query string. This is why you're seeing the authenticity token appended to your object as a query string. The solution? jQuery's $.ajax object includes an option `global`, that prevents event handlers from attaching to the request - this skirts the authenticity token being appended. Set `global` to `true`. :) (2/2)